# How to search entire dataframe and return value next to match

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below sample dataset:

```
Protocol Number:    xx-yzm2 
        
Section Major       Task                        Budget
1                   Study Setup                 25303.18
2                   Study Setup Per-Location    110037.8
3                   Site Identified by CRO      29966.25
4                   Pre-study Site Visit (PSSV) 130525.92
```

I would like to search the entire dataframe with `contains` and pass the keyword 'protocol' and return the value next to it.

Theoretically, the sheet could change so I can't filter by column. Is it possible to do with the pandas?

Input keyword would be: `protocol` output would be `xx-yzm2`

Comment: Not sure if I follow: neither the keyword (protocol), nor the output (xx-yzm2) are in the sample you've supplied. Or is `Protocol Number:    xx-yzm2` meant to be part of the `df`?

Comment: @ouroboros1 yes sorry it's not clear, that is part of a raw dataframe that I would read from an excel budget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {0: ['Protocol Number:', np.nan, 'Section Major', '1', '2', '3', '4'],
         1: ['xx-yzm2', np.nan, 'Task', 'Study Setup', 'Study Setup Per-Location', 
             'Site Identified by CRO', 'Pre-study Site Visit (PSSV)'],
         2: [np.nan, np.nan, 'Budget', '25303.18', '110037.8', '29966.25', '130525.92']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                  0                            1          2
0  Protocol Number:                      xx-yzm2        NaN
1               NaN                          NaN        NaN
2     Section Major                         Task     Budget
3                 1                  Study Setup   25303.18
4                 2     Study Setup Per-Location   110037.8
5                 3       Site Identified by CRO   29966.25
6                 4  Pre-study Site Visit (PSSV)  130525.92

keyword = 'protocol'

# case-insensitive: case=False
# row: array([0], dtype=int64), col: array([0], dtype=int64)
row, col = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.
                             contains(keyword, case=False)))

result = df.iat[row[0],col[0]+1]
print(result)

# xx-yzm2
```

If you have multiple matches, the above will get you only the *first* match. If you want to get all matches, simply use a loop. And in that case maybe add some check to error handle border cases.

```
for i in range(len(row)):
    if not col[i]+1 == len(df.columns):
        print(df.iat[row[i],col[i]+1])
    else:
        # error handle, you're keyword was found in last column, 
        # i.e. there is no `next` col
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for your help! when I try running the 1st example, I'm getting a `KeyError: 3` on this line `result = df.at[row[0],col[0]+1]`

Comment: Right, I trust that will mean that the keyword was found in the third (*and last*) column. So: `col[0] == 2` + 1 to make `3`, yet there is no `index 3` column. This is what the error handling in the below example is for, to capture matches in the last column as well, and then handle the error, since there is no next column. Does that make sense? (if not, try `print(row, col)`, what coordinates do you get?)

Comment: I get the correct col and row for the keyword. `[1] [2]` in my real dataset

Comment: it worked when I change the `at` to `iloc`: `result = df.iloc[row[0],col[0]+1]`

Comment: My bad, it should be [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) (similar to `iloc`, not `at` (sim. to `loc`). Changed that.